# appending content to a list using checkbox

Tags: jquery, clone, append

Thanks to the invaluable assistance of several Stack Overflow participants, I'm very close to the desired results ... here's a recap and update, for interested parties:

I have a series of product modules, each of which contains (among other things) the product's name and a 'compare' checkbox. My objective is to generate a list of selected products in another area of the page when the checkboxes are checked. As there must be a function to check for a minimum of two, and some arbitrary maximum - either as part of the checkbox .click function (per Brian's version, thanks again for your invaluable help), or on the submit (which I'm leaning towards). In either case, the number of items in the list is apparently being mis-counted; w/zero or one checkbox checked, I correctly get an alert of insufficient items; however, if I uncheck and recheck a few times, my code is reporting the incorrect number of items in the list.

In the interest of brevity (!), I'll forego posting both versions, since I'm experiencing similar oddity in both. Here's my latest cobbling - many thanks in advance for any insight.

```
<div class="product-module">

<div class="product-pic">
    <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
        <label for="compare1">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="compare" id="compare1" />
            Compare
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-info">
    <p>
        <a href="#" title="#"><span class="product-name">Product Name here</span></a><br />
    </p>
</div>
```

```
<div class="compare">
<ul>
</ul>
<p class="error" style="display: none;">ACK! You've selected more than 4 products to compare.</p>
<p class="compare-button"><button type="submit">Compare</button></p>
<p class="clear-selections"><a class="button" id="clear-selections" href="#">Clear Selections</a></p>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
});

$(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var title = $(this).closest('.product-module').find('.product-name').html();

        // as user checks the checkbox, add the item to the ul
        if($(this).attr('checked')){

        var html = '<li><a href="'+title+'">' + title + '</a></li>';

        $('.compare ul').append(html);
        } else {     
        // if user is un-checking the checkbox, remove the item from the ul
        // orig: $('li[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
        $('li a[href="' + title + '"]').remove();
        }
    });
});


$(function(){
    $('.clear-selections').click(function(){
        $('.compare ul').empty();
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
    })
});


$(function(){
    $('.compare button').click(function(){
        minRequests = 2;
        maxRequests = 4;
        requested = $('.compare ul li').size();    // go figure: why not .length()?

        if(requested < 2)    {
        alert ('Compare ' + requested + ' products?');

        } else if((requested >= 2) && (requested <= 5 ))    {
        alert ('There are ' + requested + ' products to compare');

        } else {
        alert (requested + ' is too many');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You realise that in your jQuery you're looking for a `.product-module` which doesn't appear to exist in the html you provided?

Comment: when you're trying to present blocks of code in your question, you can indent the each of the lines of code by four spaces; **or** select all the text that you want to show as code and *either* click the `101010` above the text-area *or* hit ctrl + K. For in-line code just use backticks on either side. Please read the [Markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thx for pointing this out; it's only because I'd modified the classes for the purpose of the question, as I'm successfully targeting the product name

Comment: No worries, any chance you could give a simple step-by-step description of what you want to happen once the checkbox is checked? I'm not sure, looking at your jQuery, quite what's going on (*sorry*).

Comment: Thanks David.

Once the checkbox is checked, the corresponding product name is added to a list. The checkbox and product name are not siblings, so I use .find() to target the product-name. If there's a better option, I'm all ears. The problem is that each click is doubly adding the product name to the list. I'm also concerned with how to remove content from the list if a checkbox is un-checked.

Hope I'm making sense, appreciate your patience and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the approach I take: http://jsfiddle.net/ek2zh/  I didn't use clone because the node you want to paste is a span and you want to clone it into an li.  Not sure clone will automatically adjust the node as desired.

Comment: Thanks Brian! This version looks very much how I thought it could. I haven't got it working yet, not sure why, I'm gonna have to play with it

Comment: Hello again and thanks again, I do have a very slightly modified version of your solution working. The product names will be drawn from a db so until I have from my client the precise format of that content, I won't trouble anyone with how to mod the html ;) ... my next question is how to limit the number of list items, and alert the user (e.g., unhide an error) when they try to select more than the max allowed. Perhaps I should add a fresh question, so I can show the jQuery so far

Comment: No worries.  I updated a fork with an alert box.  http://jsfiddle.net/G8yVe/  All I'm doing is setting a max amount and checking before I add a new li against the current count of li's

Comment: Thanks Brian. You've actually proceeded as I originally planned (though your help was necessary): I mean to say by validating min/max entries as the user checks a checkbox. However, it also makes sense to me to have the validation instead on the submit, and oddly enough I'm experiencing similar (imperfect) results either way: The jQ is somehow miscounting what's been added to the list, perhaps counting checks & un-checks? I'd like to share both versions so I'll try to post an answer to my question with the code. Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your code is cloning the .product-name clone and cloning it again. Try using a more specific path to target the element your cloning, instead of the find method.